# How to add og:image metatag for drupal 7 video.

Tags: drupal, video, drupal-7, meta-tags

I'm using drupal 7 and Video Embed Field 7.x-2.0-beta5 with Metatags 7.x-1.0-beta1.

On the other hand, I have a content type with a video field. The teaser is showing the thumbnail properly, and the default view is showing the video as well.

What I want/need is to create an og:image metatag with the video thumbnail (the same thumbnail as the teaser view) 
In the metatag configuration I'm using OpenGraphImage = [node:field_video] but it's not working ...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to add some code at template.php

```
function andromeda_preprocess_node(&$variables) {

global $base_url; 
    $img = $base_url.base_path().path_to_theme()."/logo.jpg"; 
    if($variables['is_front'] != TRUE){ 
        if(isset($variables['node']->field_imagenes['und'][0]['uri'])){ 
            $img = file_create_url($variables['node']->field_imagenes['und'][0]['uri']); 
        }
        else if(isset($variables['node']->field_video['und'][0]['thumbnail_path'])){ 
            $img = file_create_url($variables['node']->field_video['und'][0]['thumbnail_path']); 
        }   
    } 

    $element = array(
        '#tag' => 'meta',
        '#attributes' => array(
            "property" => "og:image",
            "content" => $img,
                ),
            );

    drupal_add_html_head($element,'facebook_share_image');
```

That is working great!